# How can I programmatically set the width of a column in Slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using SlickGid 2.0 and I'd like to be able to set the width of each column based on the longest string contained in the column.  I'm fine calculating the required width, but I cannot figure out how to set the width of a column outside of faking a drag event.  Is there any other way to individually set the widths of columns in SlickGrid?

Answer (score 1):

According to comments in the source code, you can set `model[cell].width` to adjust the width of individual columns.

See comments here:

http://code.google.com/p/slickgrid/source/browse/trunk/slick.grid.js?r=9